# rails - call json api and parse one value in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm calling a json api and retrieving this as the result every single time:

```
{
  "@endDate": "2016-11-05",
  "@metric": "Sessions",
  "@startDate": "2016-11-05",
  "@generatedDate": "11\/5\/16 6:14 PM",
  "@version": "1.0",
  "day": {
    "@date": "2016-11-05",
    "@value": "8174"
  }
}
```

I want to get the number 8174 in a variable in rails, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assign your json response to `response` variable

`response = {
  "@endDate": "2016-11-05",
  "@metric": "Sessions",
  "@startDate": "2016-11-05",
  "@generatedDate": "11\/5\/16 6:14 PM",
  "@version": "1.0",
  "day": {
    "@date": "2016-11-05",
    "@value": "8174"
  }
}`

## Parse it

`parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.to_josn)`

## After parsing `parsed_response` is now a hash. So you can access the `number` from `parsed_response` hash

`get_number = parsed_response['day']['@value']`

Comment: getting this error `ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Hash into String):` Thank you

Comment: By any chance, do you know what would be the best way to call the api? I just realized I worded this questions as if that part was done. Thank you

Comment: Edited. I forgot to add `to_json`. To call an api I usually use `rest-client` gem and receive the response this way(my answer).